# Pandas reposition column values based on values

Tags: python, pandas

I've this sample table as below:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|
|---|---|---|
|dog|cat|bike|
|cat|bike|dog|
|NaN|car|NaN|
```

In pandas, is there any method to rearrange the column values for each row such that all same values are in same column as below:

```
|col_1|col_2|col_3|col_4|
|---|---|---|
|dog|cat|bike|NaN|
|dog|cat|bike|NaN|
|NaN|NaN|NaN|car|
```

Missing values should be replaced with NaN. 
Thanks.

Comment: Why not just work with dummy columns? Seems more natural to have a columns named 'dog', 'cat', 'bike', 'car' and 1 and 0s indicating whether that row has that value.

Comment: The columns generated after doing a regex search.

Comment: Yes, but so what? This is still a very inefficient way to store things like this. What happens if you have something like `dog bike bike bike bike bike bike`, Do we need 6 different columns all to indicate multiple instances of bike? Would be far more natural to have a column named 'bike' with the number 6 in it for that row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more like a `get_dummies` problem

```
s=df.stack().str.get_dummies()
yourdf=s.sum(level=0).mul(s.columns)
yourdf
   bike  car  cat  dog
0  bike       cat  dog
1  bike       cat  dog
2        car
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Follow-up question: What does "mul(s.columns)" do here? I get the correct output even when I don't use them. If I use "mul", I get this error ```TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21') dtype('<U21')```

Comment: @SamiraKumar mul here treat the 1 equal to True and if it will check every row if True , it will return the value of columns , if False it will return empty

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot :)